# Как сократить кол-во строк с "повторяющимися" функциями для кнопок Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

У меня есть 10 кнопок. Нажав на каждую меняется текст. Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли как-то сократить кол-во функций и строк?

Мой код:

```
    public void PreceptView()
    {
        PreceptViewManager("Заповедь №1\nСатана олицетворяет потворство, а не в-здержание!");
    }
    public void PreceptView1()
    {
        PreceptViewManager("За-ВедЬ №2\nСатана оли-цеоотворяет жизненную суть вместо несбыточных духовных мечтаний.");
    }
    public void PreceptView2()
    {
        PreceptViewManager("Заповedь №3\nSatan олицетворяет неOsквернённую мудрость вместо лицемерного самообмана!");
    }
...
```

Comment: как насчёт хранить все заповеди в файле json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Реализация через `константы + enum + switch-case`**

Записи о заповедях хранятся в константах, в инспекторе нужно закрепить скрипт, и выбрать нужную заповедь через enum, на обьекте со скриптом должен быть `Button`, при старте он подпишиться на событие нажатия и вызовит метод используя выбранное enum значение через `switch-case`

```
private const string PRECEPT_1 = "Заповедь 1";
private const string PRECEPT_2 = "Заповедь 2";
private const string PRECEPT_3 = "Заповедь 3";
private const string PRECEPT_NULL = "Заповедь не обнаружена";

private Button _button;

[SerializeField] private PreceptNumber _preceptNumber;

public enum PreceptNumber
{
    Precept1,
    Precept2,
    Precept3
}

public void Start()
{
    _button = GetComponent<Button>();

    _button.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClickHandler);
}

public void Destroy()
{
    _button.onClick.RemoveListener(ButtonClickHandler);
}

public void ButtonClickHandler()
{
    string message = "";

    switch (_preceptNumber)
    {
        case PreceptNumber.Precept1:
            message = PRECEPT_1;
            break;
        case PreceptNumber.Precept2:
            message = PRECEPT_2;
            break;
        case PreceptNumber.Precept3:
            message = PRECEPT_3;
            break;
        default:
            message = "PRECEPT_NULL;
            break;
    }

    PreceptViewManager(message);
}
```

**Реализация через `Dictionary<>`**

Вариант через словари, заполняем заранее заповеди, можно и в любой другой момент, показан для примера инициализация сразу

```
    private Dictionary<PreceptNumber, string> _preceptMap =
        new Dictionary<PreceptNumber, string>()
        {
            [PreceptNumber.Precept1] = "Заповедь 1",
            [PreceptNumber.Precept2] = "Заповедь 2",
            [PreceptNumber.Precept3] = "Заповедь 3",
            [PreceptNumber.Precept4] = "Заповедь 4",
            [PreceptNumber.Precept5] = "Заповедь 5",
        };

    private Button _button;

    [SerializeField] private PreceptNumber _preceptNumber;

    [System.Serializable]
    public enum PreceptNumber
    {
        Precept1,
        Precept2,
        Precept3,
        Precept4,
        Precept5
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _button = GetComponent<Button>();

        _button.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClickHandler);
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        _button.onClick.RemoveListener(ButtonClickHandler);
    }

    public void ButtonClickHandler()
    {
        PreceptViewManager(_preceptMap[_preceptNumber]);
    }
```

**Реализация без хранения данных**

Вызов через заполнение поля в инспекторе, заповеди нигде не хранятся

```
    private Button _button;

    [SerializeField] private string _precept;

    public void Start()
    {
        _button = GetComponent<Button>();

        _button.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClickHandler);
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        _button.onClick.RemoveListener(ButtonClickHandler);
    }

    public void ButtonClickHandler()
    {
        PreceptViewManager(_precept);
    }
```

Использование `enum` позволяет удобно выбирает в инспекторе значение, исключает вероятность случайных ошибок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а для чего нужно перечисление `PreceptNumber`? Тут же заповеди это просто строковые данные, которые можно хранить в словаре по типу такого: `[1]="Заповедь 1", ...`, а enum подходит больше для ограниченного и относительно постоянного множества

Comment: @iiKuzmychov, В инспекторе можно удобно выбирать нужную заповедь, и используя этот выбор как ключ искать в словаре

Comment: разве в инспекторе выбрать `Precept1` намного удобнее чем вписать 1?

Comment: @iiKuzmychov, конечно, я дополнил ответ скриншотом, когда выбираешь через перечисление ты исключаешь вероятность случайного изменения строкового поля, которое может принять абсолютно любое значение, и это сложно проконтролировать, а enum вынуждает тебя выбрать из списка

Comment: @iiKuzmychov, может это удобно только для меня, но я правда считаю что это надежнее

Comment: статическое исключения ошибок это круто, но делать отдельное свойство для enum под каждую заповедь кажеться мне неправильным

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138144/discussion-between-alemkhan-utepkaliev-and-iikuzmychov).

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - создать словарь, у которого в качестве ключа будут номера заповедей, а в качестве значения - тексты заповедей:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> _precepts;
```

Затем при старте скрипта инициализируете этот словарь:

```
public void Start()
{
    _precepts = new()
    {
        [1] = "Заповедь 1 ...",
        [2] = "Заповедь 2 ...",
    };
    // или же можно инициализировать словарь из json-файла, если эти данные вам пригодятся и вне этого класса
}
```

Затем осталось использовать его:

```
public void PreceptView(int preceptNumber)
{
    PreceptViewManager(_precepts[preceptNumber]);
}
```

P.S.

Не уверен, будет ли это так работать, но если вы установите [этот](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/dropdown-attribute-180951#releases) ассет, то, возможно,  вы сможете, вместо вписывания номера заповеди в инспекторе, выбирать номер из списка:

```
public void PreceptView([Dropdown(nameof(_precepts) + ".Keys")] int preceptNumber)
{
    PreceptViewManager(_precepts[preceptNumber]);
}
```